# Remove the redundant equations from a list of equations

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a list of polynomial equations that represent constraints on a system, but they are not independent and are therefore some are redundant.

my real list is very long. A simple example would be

```
eqns = {x^2+y^2 == 1, -x^2-y^2 == -1}
```

I'm not trying to (nor could I) solve the system of equations. I'd just like to have a list that contains only independent constraints. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) all the equations and then use [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)
 like this: `Simplify /@ {x^2 + y^2 == 1, -x^2 - y^2 == -1} // DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: Simplify is leaving the equations in a non-identical format (eg out by an overall minus sign) so DeleteDuplicates does not recognise them as being duplicates

Comment: Did the above code work for those equations?

Comment: it does seem to work when I incorporate my eqtns in code you specify but not when I simplify them independently then perform DeleteDuplicates after.  Does your simplify code somehow enforce a more uniform result from Simplify?

Comment: That's strange.  I'm not getting different results even if I apply `Simplify[]` separately. Can you post what you have tried?. Btw I'm on v11.1.0.

Comment: i think i must be causing issues when I do something like Simplify[Flatten[test1] == 0] and Simplify[Flatten[test2] == 0] where test1 and test2 are a matrices of equations, as this is when redundent eqnts do not simplify identically.  Anyway, I have a work around.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Simplify` and `DeleteDuplicates` may not work, if some expressions are more complex than the one in your example, but still dependent. For example, `x^2 + y^2 == 1` and `-x^2 - y^2 + 1/(-x^2 - y^2) == -2`. Simplify transforms the latter expression into `(-1 + x^2 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2) == 0` which is not recognized as a duplicate. In such a case `Reduce` helps. `Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && -x^2 - y^2 + 1/(-x^2 - y^2) == -2, y]` returns  `y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2] || y == Sqrt[1 - x^2]`.

Comment: It seems that `Eliminate[eqns, {}]` would do the trick? Could you give more examples or explain more about the real equations?

Answer (score 3):

I think this question deserves a formal answer.

Let;s work a slightly more complicated example.

```
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 == 1, -x^2 - y^2 + 1 == 0, 5 x - 1 == y, y == 5 x - 1};
eqns // Simplify // DeleteDuplicates
```

`{x^2 + y^2 == 1, 5 x == 1 + y}`

The idea is to regularize the equations and delete the duplicates.